# New column added in Pandas not being recognized

Tags: python, pandas, median

I created a new column in my dataset called deaths_to_cases (this is a dataframe about COVID-19 cases in the United States). For some reason, anything I want to try and do, like get the median of this new column, isn't being recognized in Pandas - I'm using Google Colab.

The code is below, and I even tested an existing column that was in the dataframe I uploaded as the CSV file (existing column='positive'), and it worked. The problem is the df.loc[:,'deaths_to_cases'].median(). I'm newer to Python/pandas so I'm sure it's an obvious fix and I'm just too new to know. Any help much appreciated!

```
df.assign(deaths_to_cases = df.death/df.positive)
df.info()
df.loc[:,'positive'].median()
df.loc[:,'deaths_to_cases'].median()
```

Comment: `assign` returns a new dataframe. You may want to reassign: `df = df.assign(...)`.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much!